# Internet Radio Tuner integrated with SHOUTcast

Tags: shoutcast, internet-radio

How does an internet radio tuner integrated with SHOUTcast work?  How does it switch from one station to other through SHOUTcast?

Are there SHOUTcast API's available in Java to implement an internet radio tuner?

Answer (score 1):

Shoutcast seems to have removed their API documentation since they got bought by Radionomy.

You can use third party API's like [streamfinder radio stations](http://www.streamfinder.com/) (http://www.streamfinder.com/internet-radio-api/) and [Dirble.com Internet radio directory](http://dirble.com) (http://dirble.com/api) - These provide with api in different classes and structure.

You might find one you like.

(To be clear, i am the one behind Dirble)

Answer (score 0):

SHOUTcast stations are just streaming MP3 over a protocol very similar (in fact, compatible) with HTTP.  If you want to switch from one station to another, you simply stop one and start playing another.

There is no need for a huge API for querying SHOUTcast's directory.  You can find the information here:  http://dev.aol.com/SHOUTcast/documentation

Answer (score 0):

In general there´s 2 types of shoutcast tuners.

1)

The programmer did (manually) create a list of preset stations (urls)
a user can switch between them.

2)

The tuner takes its info dynamicly from the shoutcast page (or api)
it will look for tags ("genres" like rock,pop,house..etc)
which a shoutcast-server (radiostation) does send to the shoutcast website.